# I need to have a form that will show prices for some people and hide from others, but it's a listbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I need to have a form that will show prices for some people and hide from others, but it's a listbox.
How do I do?
The only solution I found is to change the cols width, but is not really...

Comment: What's wrong with hidding the column by setting its width to 0? Why is that not a satisfactory solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the Listbox or combo box rowsource / recordsource details based on Windows login or Access login if you have built in security.

Some sort of If statement in conjuntion with the Login API, which you could find by googling. An example would be kind of like below (do this on the on load event maybe?) -

Dim UserName As String

UserName = GetUserName_TSB 'this is the windows login drawn from the LoginAPI function

If UserName = "XXXX" Or UserName = "XXXXX" Or UserName = "XXXXX" Or UserName = "XXXX" Then

Me.combobox.rowsource = 'Create a SELECT SQL query for whatever your tables / data is.

Else

Me.combobox.rowsource = 'Create a SELECT SQL query for whatever your tables / data is for other users

End If

Comment: the problem is that I also get the wrong spacing between cols because if one is missing then the others will step in.. I might put the cost as hidden and is solved! instant IDEA! hehe. then use your answer. thanks